# Delayed job: How to process job sequentially (one after another)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job

I am running delayed job with command `RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job start`.

i am storing jobs with below code

`Delayed::Job.enqueue QrCodeGenerator.new(client,request,params[:batch_quantity].to_i)`

Currently delayed job is running jobs simeltanoulsy. i want know how to run job one after another.

Thanks,

Comment: I am also facing the issue with multiple workers, I have 4 workers so it assign 4 job at asynchronous i want one after another

Answer (score 0):

1. If this job is always gonna be the same job but just with different input parameters, you can just run `QUEUE=myqueue rake jobs:work` because that rake process will run one job at a time. You can then run another simultaneous delayed_job rake process to run other queues as a concurrent worker (if you have other jobs that needs to be processed).
2. If the sequential jobs you are talking about however are of different jobs / class, then you can just call the other job once the first job has finished.

Comment: I'm wondering, how can you achieve 2? [I posted a question exactly about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47946534/run-rails-jobs-sequentially) (running two different jobs sequentially), if you can provide some help, it would be greatly appreciated!