# Run Rails jobs sequentially

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jobs

I have three Rails jobs to process a player yellow/red cards in a soccer tournament, and the penalties these players will have due to getting this cards.
The idea is that the first job collects all Incidences (an Incidence is when a Player gets a yellow card, to give an example), and counts *all* the cards a Player got.

```
class ProcessBookedPlayersJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default
  @cards = []

  def perform(*args)
    @cards = []
    yellows = calculate_cards(1)
    reds = calculate_cards(2)
    @cards << yellows << reds
  end

  def after_perform(*match)
    #ProcessPenaltiesJob.perform_later @cards
    ProcessPenalties.perform_later @cards
    #PenaltiesFinalizerJob.perform_later match
    PenaltiesFinalizer.perform_later match
  end

  def calculate_cards(card_type)
    cards = Hash.new
    players = Player.fetch_players_with_active_incidences
    players.each { |p|
      # 1 is yellow, 2 is red
      counted_cards = Incidence.incidences_for_player_id_and_incidence_type(p.id, card_type).size
      cards[p] = counted_cards
    }
    return cards
  end
end
```

This first job is executed when an Instance is created.

```
class Incidence < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :match

  after_save :process_incidences, on: :create

  def self.incidences_for_player_id_and_incidence_type(player_id, card_type)
    return Incidence.where(status: 1).where(incidence_type: card_type).where(player_id: player_id)
  end

  protected
  def process_incidences
    ProcessBookedPlayers.perform_later
  end
end
```

After this, another job runs and creates the necessary Penalties (a Penalty is a ban for the next Match, for example) according to the Hash output that the previous job created.

```
class ProcessPenaltiesJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(*cards)
    yellows = cards[0]
    reds = cards[1]
    create_penalties_for_yellow_cards(yellows)
    create_penalties_for_red_cards(reds)
  end

  # rest of the job...
```

And also there's another job, that sets these bans as disabled, once they have expired.

```
class PenaltiesFinalizerJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(match)
    active_penalties = Penalty.find_by(status: 1)
    active_penalties.each do |p|
      #penalty.starting_match.order + penalty.length == el_match_que_inserte.order (ver si seria >=)
      if p.match.order + p.length >= match.order
        p.status = 2    # Inactivate
        p.save!
      end
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see in `ProcessBookedPlayersJob`'s `after_perform` method

```
def after_perform(*match)
    ProcessPenalties.perform_later @cards
    PenaltiesFinalizer.perform_later match
end
```

I'm trying to get those two other jobs executed (`ProcessPenaltiesJob` and `PenaltiesFinalizerJob`) with no luck. The job `ProcessBookedPlayersJob` is being executed (because I can see this in the log)

```
[ActiveJob] [ProcessBookedPlayersJob] [dbb8445e-a706-4443-9cb8-2c45f49a4f8f] Performed ProcessBookedPlayersJob (Job ID: dbb8445e-a706-4443-9cb8-2c45f49a4f8f) from Async(default) in 38.81ms
```

But the other two jobs aren't executed. So, how can I get both `ProcessPenaltiesJob` and `PenaltiesFinalizerJob` run after `ProcessBookedPlayersJob` has finalized its execution? I don't mind if they run in parallel, but they need to be run after the first one finishes, since they need its output as their input.

I have searched for this, and the closest match I found was [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34740492/3923525). Quoting it:

> If the sequential jobs you are talking about however are of different
>   jobs / class, then you can just call the other job once the first job
>   has finished.

That's *exactly* the behaviour I'm trying to have... but how can I get my jobs to run sequentially?
For now, I'm thinking in adding the first job's logic into `Incidences`'s `after_save`hook, but that doesn't sound too natural. Is there any other way to pipeline the execution of my jobs?
Many thanks in advance

Comment: My answer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34739958/delayed-job-how-to-process-job-sequentially-one-after-another/34740492#34740492) only works if the jobs already know what jobs to execute after they finished. However, in your case your first job is the one responsible for executing sequentially two jobs. Therefore, you may be interested instead on using [sidekiq-superworker](https://github.com/socialpandas/sidekiq-superworker). If you're not using sidekiq, let me know and I think I can come up with my own solution.

Comment: I'll check the gem, thanks